# Workflow triggers after every commit but should not

Tags: github-actions

I have a GitHub Actions workflow that adds a comment with a checklist when a Pull Request is opened or reopened. It is an action that runs on multiple repos in our org.

It seemed to work fine until one or two months ago, when suddenly the action would trigger after every commit on the Pull Request.

```
name: Add comment to pull requests

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, reopened]

jobs:
  add-comment:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Add comment to pull request
        uses: actions/github-script@v5
        with:
          github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          script: |
            github.rest.issues.createComment({
              issue_number: context.issue.number,
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              body: `## ‍ Vérifications

              ### Faciliter la review
              - [ ] Ajouter le lien de la PR sur la carte Trello ***et*** ajouter le lien du ticket sur la PR
              - [ ] Ajouter le **label** lié à l'environnement de développement sur la pull request (env-preprod, env-dev, env-local...)
              - [ ] Préciser le lien, si existant, pour tester les devs
              - [ ] Ajouter le **label** \`\`\`en attente\`\`\` si la PR n'est pas prête
                `
            });
```

I initially considered whether the "synchronize" event might have been causing the "reopened" event to trigger. However, even after removing it, there were no changes in behavior.

How to fix it, so it only triggers when a pull request is opened or re-opened?

Is there a way for me to obtain more detailed information about what specifically triggered the action, beyond the current message format, which only provides information like "Add comment to pull requests #7: Pull request synchronize by ...."?

Comment: That workflow configuration looks correct, it should only run on commits if the synchronize type is included.

Comment: According to [GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request) the trigger looks correct.